# Write a valueStock function that takes an array of products as a parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Write a valueStock function that takes an array of products as a parameter. The function must return a new arrangement with objects that have the name of each product and the total value of the stock.

```
var products= [{ name: 'TV LCD', price: 100, stock: 50 }, { name: 'pc', price: 500, stock: 50 }, { name: 'Iphone', price: 1000, stock: 10 }]
var valorStock= function(arreglo){
  var array=[]
   for(var i=0; i<arreglo.length; i++){
      array[productos[i]["name"]]=productos[i]["price"]*["stock"]

   }
   return array
}
console.log(valorStock(productos))
```

I expect this output:`[{ TV LCD: 5000 }, { Computadora: 25000 }, { Iphone: 10000 }]`

Comment: Instead of `productos[i]["price"]*["stock"]` you need to say `productos[i]["price"] * productos[i]["stock"]`, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```js
var products = [{
  name: 'TV LCD',
  price: 100,
  stock: 50
}, {
  name: 'pc',
  price: 500,
  stock: 50
}, {
  name: 'Iphone',
  price: 1000,
  stock: 10
}]
var valorStock = function(arreglo) {
  var array = []
  for (var i = 0, p; p = arreglo[i]; i++) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[p.name] = p.price * p.stock;
    array.push(obj);

  }
  return array
}

// or better
var valorStock1 = function(arreglo) {
  return arreglo.map(p => {
    var obj = {};
    obj[p.name] = p.price * p.stock;
    return obj;
  });
}

console.log(valorStock(products));
console.log(valorStock1(products));
```

Answer (score 3):

The function can be achieved in 1 line if you take advantage of [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

```js
var products = [{
  name: 'TV LCD',
  price: 100,
  stock: 50
}, {
  name: 'pc',
  price: 500,
  stock: 50
}, {
  name: 'Iphone',
  price: 1000,
  stock: 10
}];

//This is the function you need
const valueStock = arr => arr.map(el => ({[el.name]: el.price * el.stock}));

console.log(valueStock(products));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first keep track of the products in an object and then convert it to an array using `Object.entries`:

```js
var products = [{
  name: 'TV LCD',
  price: 100,
  stock: 50
}, {
  name: 'pc',
  price: 500,
  stock: 50
}, {
  name: 'Iphone',
  price: 1000,
  stock: 10
}]

var valorStock = function(arreglo) {
  var result = {};
  arreglo.forEach(({name, price, stock}) => {
    result[name] = result[name] || 0;
    result[name] += price * stock;
  });
  return Object.entries(result).map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v}));
}
console.log(valorStock(products))
```

If each element in `products` is unique (has a unique name), you can also simply get your result with `map`:

```js
var products = [{
  name: 'TV LCD',
  price: 100,
  stock: 50
}, {
  name: 'pc',
  price: 500,
  stock: 50
}, {
  name: 'Iphone',
  price: 1000,
  stock: 10
}]

var valorStock = function(arreglo) {
  return arreglo.map(({name, price, stock}) => ({[name]: price * stock}))
}
console.log(valorStock(products))
```

Comment: Thanks! But i need it in a more simple way. Using push().

Comment: @GonAlb you can simply convert the `map` version to use an separate array to which you can `push` the newly created objects as you iterate through `products`.